# How to make contour plot map and overcome no contour level were found?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, contour

So I'm newbie in python and I have a project making contour plot map. I have a data in xlsx contain `x`, `y`, and `z` values. **`x`** and **`y`** are the coordinates and **`z`** are the measurement values.

```
1. x        ;  y       ; z
2. 110.4482 ; 7.04428  ; 0.177
3. 110.4451 ; 7.04366  ; 0.102
4. 110.4432 ; 7.04432  ; 0.482
5. 110.4407 ; 7.04434  ; 0.504
```

I want to make a contour like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoTUj.png)
[image]
I tried to make a contour but when I run it, it appear a blank picture [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kquWM.png) 
[image]

and a note:

> warnings.warn("No contour levels were found"
>
> UserWarning: No contour levels were found within the data range.
>
> xa[xa < 0] = -1 RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
>
> : usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/contour.py:1243:
>   UserWarning: No contour levels were found within the data range.
>   warnings.warn("No contour levels were found"

This is the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as ml
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

xlsx_path =('Book1.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx_path)

x = df.iloc[1:20,0]
y = df.iloc[1:20,1]
z = df.iloc[1:20,2]
xi = np.linspace(6, 8, 20)
yi = np.linspace(109, 111, 20)
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
plt.contour(xi, yi, zi)
plt.show()
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: We cannot find out why your code fails. Instead of your actual data you need to make the case reproducible (see [mcve] or http://sscce.org)

Comment: should I interpolated my data? @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Yes, but you're doing that already. See first comment.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *How can I fix it?*

Just swap and adapt the `x, y`-ranges, for which you try to plot the there tabelled `z`-values derived cubic-contours.

You plot a "*wrong*"-( ill-defined )-region of data, where no `z`-level contours have evolved to get computed the less displayed.

```
xi = np.linspace(  6,   8, 20)  # actual data-values are ~ ( 110.437 : 110.448 )
yi = np.linspace(109, 111, 20)  # actual data-values are ~ (   7.042 :   7.050 )
```